# Building and looping over list in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I've the following code, which will (hopefully) generate a list of length total-pop, where each element is a number from 1 - no-of-patches.

```
to setup-agents
  ;; create list of patch values from 1 - no-of-patches
  let j 3
  let tmp random (no-of-patches - 1)
  set tmp tmp + 1
  let patch-designation list ((random no-of-patches) + 1) ((random no-of-patches) + 1)
  loop [
    ;; create a list
    set tmp random no-of-patches 
    set tmp tmp + 1 ;; so it's 1 - no-of-patches
    set patch-designation lput tmp patch-designation
    set j j + 1
    if j > total-pop [ stop ]
    show length patch-designation
  ]
  show length patch-designation

end
```

I've a number of questions which didn't seem appropriate in individual questions on this site. (1) Online I found that one will define a list like `set my-list [ 1 2 3 ]`. However, when I try `set patch-designation []`, to create an empty list, I get an error ("Nothing named PATCH-DESIGNATION has been defined"). In fact, this happens *whenever* I use `set patch-designation [ some numbers ]`. `set patch-designation [ 1 2 3 ]` produces the same error, even though it's almost exactly like the online tutorial. (2) If I include `show length patch-designation` inside the loop, I see it updated during each iteration. However, if I place it outside the loop, I see no output. In fact, if I type `show length patch-designation` inside the console it reads that there is no such variable. Why is that?

If you couldn't tell, I'm a beginner - any criticism on the remaining code is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works fine for me when I use `let patch-designation []` to initiate the list. Note however that I used `let` not `set` because I wanted to declare its existence as well as set the value to empty. That is why you are getting an error but you used `let` in your provided code with the other form of list initiation.

```
to setup-agents
  let total-pop 100
  let no-of-patches count patches
  ;; create list of patch values from 1 - no-of-patches
  let j 3
  let tmp random (no-of-patches - 1)
  set tmp tmp + 1
  let patch-designation []
  loop [
    ;; create a list
    set tmp random no-of-patches 
    set tmp tmp + 1 ;; so it's 1 - no-of-patches
    set patch-designation lput tmp patch-designation
    set j j + 1
    if j > total-pop [ stop ]
    show length patch-designation
  ]
  show length patch-designation
end
```

More generally, I have two comments about the code. If you want a list of length total-pop that contains randomly generated numbers from 1 to the number of patches, this single line will do the same thing:

```
let patch-designation n-values total-pop [1 + random count patches]
```

The first part `let patch-designation` creates a new variable called patch-designation. `n-values total-pop` says that you want a list of size total-pop that is generated by the expression in []. Inside the [] is simply calling the random number generator that gets an integer from 0 up to but not including the number of patches (`count patches`) and then adds 1.

The reason you are not getting output is because the `stop` command exits the whole procedure, not just the loop.

Look up in the dictionary: `let`, `set`, `loop` and `n-values` to help you understand my comments.

You didn't say why you are creating this list. But you are calling it patch-designation and the procedure is called setup-agents, which makes me think you will be using the numbers you have generated as some sort of identifier for patches where you want agents to be created. If that's what you are doing, then there are much better ways of doing it. Patches already have identifiers so you don't need to assign one, and almost always you should be using agentsets rather than lists.

For example, if you want to generate 100 turtles, each at a different patch, try this:

```
to setup-agents
  ask n-of 100 patches
  [ sprout 1
  ]
end
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the restriction of different patches, so they can be generated at the same patch, try this:

```
to setup-agents
  repeat 100
  [ ask one-of patches
    [ sprout 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much for your assistance/ advice!!